# IMAP account in MS outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've created an account with IMAP protocol.
All goes well until the moment when I open my Outlook. Then is created in a subdirectory and a Hard Drive which I do not want a pst file.
What should I do to change the location of the pst file only for that account?
Because all other outlook functions normally

Answer (score -1):

Am unsure of which version of Microsoft Outlook you are using but Microsoft has several detailed guides

**Microsoft Office Outlook® 2003 & Microsoft Outlook® 2000 and 2002**

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-your-outlook-data-file-to-another-location-HA001112480.aspx

**Locate, move or backup PST file**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291636

**Step by step guide from How to geeks**

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21384/where-is-my-pst-file-and-how-can-i-move-it-somewhere-else/